# What is "to have the price of tea"?

Tags: word-meaning

"Speak to me?" Rosemary turned. She saw a little creature, no older than herself who shivered as though she had just come out of the water. "Madam," came the voice, **"would you let me have the price of a cup of tea?"** "A cup of tea?" There was something simple, sincere in that voice; it couldn't be the voice of a beggar. "Then have you no money at all?" asked Rosemary. "None, madam", came the answer.

Comment: It's not "the price of tea", it's a set phrase "the price of a cup of tea". A small sum of money, not necessarily to be spent on buying a cup of tea in a cafe.

Answer (score 4):

It means simply "Will you give me enough money to buy a cup of tea?" Nothing more complex.

Comment: When I was a boy in London, elderly male beggars used to say "Could you let an old soldier have the price of a cup of tea?"

Comment: My immediate interpretation was, *Can you tell me how much a cup of tea costs?* No doubt this is more of an idiom in the UK than the US. But strictly from the syntax itself, I can see both interpretations. Having said that, the dialogue that follows makes it obvious that yours is the correct interpretation in the passage itself.

Comment: @JasonBassford: of course it could have that meaning. But context is everything. I think "the price of" is a way of avoiding mentioning that dirty thing, money.